# Django JsonResponse: User matching query does not exist

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views

So I´ve tried to make an ajax for my models but it is giving me a matching query does not exist, here is the full error:

```
Internal Server Error: /messages/notification/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 106, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Python & Javascript\Web development\MiFamiliaEsUnDesastre\mifamiliaesundesastre\chat\views.py", line 26, in get_object
    obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
File "C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Python & Javascript\Web development\MiFamiliaEsUnDesastre\mifamiliaesundesastre\chat\models.py", line 29, in get_or_new
    user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
HTTP GET /messages/notification/ 500 [0.16, 127.0.0.1:56012]
```

Also here is my code:
models.py

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        #to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        to = User,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

views.py

```
def notifications(request, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.profile.notifications = user.profile.notifications + 1
    user.save()
    return JsonResponse(data=user.profile.notifications, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
path('messages/notification/', notifications)
```

my html for the ajax call

```
// Add the notification val
$.get('notification/')
```

someone tell me that is that I dont have users, but when I do have a user, I dont know what is going on

Comment: yep, the same problem here

Comment: you havent provide a user_id argument on that call that is the reason

Comment: @KishanParmar So do I need to get rid of the user_id and just put pk=1?

Comment: get rig of user_id in the url patterns + and delete user_id in the first line of views.py arguments    and  after that use user=request.user thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send `user_id` to the view:

```
path('messages/notification/(?P<user_id>[a-zA-Z0-9/_\.-]*)', notifications)
```

and:

```
$.get('messages/notification/{{ user.pk }}')
```

**Update**

You have to know their user id to get their notifications:

```
$.get('messages/notification/12234')
```

I assume you have a User model somewhere?

Also, `user_id` is coming in as a string, so need to `int()` that:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=int(user_id))
```

Or use:

```
path('messages/notification/<int:user_id>', notifications)
```

Comment: it doesnt work, when I go to messages/notification is when the user matching query does not exits

Comment: You're going to have to log inside your `notification` function to see what's going on.  Also, `user_id` is coming in as a string, so need to `int()` that.  See update

Comment: I already post a new question, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378988/django-update-a-model-value-on-websocket-recieve

Comment: What is the resolution to this current answer?

Comment: but if I can solve the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378988/django-update-a-model-value-on-websocket-recieve I can solve this one

Answer (score -1):

So for does who saw this later, what I did is to change the

```
path('messages/notification/', notifications)
```

To

```
url(r'^ajax/notification/$', notification),
```

Comment: There was no way to know that from the code you posted.

Comment: @GAEfan Yes, sorry about that, but thank you very much, Im going to give you a good answer